# Why does Akka stream flow not work?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Akka stream pipeline works fine without take(2) but with take(2) does not display any output. How does take() function make a difference?

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import scala.util.Try
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._

object TestStream {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("MyTest")
    implicit val Matt = ActorMaterializer()

    def mainflow():Unit ={
        val grp = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
        implicit builder =>
        import GraphDSL.Implicits._
        val src:Outlet[Int] = builder.add(Source(1 to 10)).out
        val flw1:FlowShape[Int, Int] = builder.add(Flow[Int].map(x => x*10).take(2))
        val flw2:FlowShape[Int, Int] = builder.add(Flow[Int].filter(x => x > 50))
        val snk2:Inlet[Any] = builder.add(Sink.foreach(println)).in
        src ~> flw1 ~> flw2 ~> snk2
        ClosedShape
        }).run
    }
    def main(str:Array[String]):Unit = {
        mainflow()
    }
}
```

**Just for reference added the Test result without take():** spark\bin\spark-submit --class TestStream --master local[2] --jars config-1.2.1.jar,akka-actor_2.11-2.4.2.jar,reactive-s treams-1.0.0.jar,akka-stream_2.11-2.4.2.jar target\scala-2.11\simple-project_2.1 1-1.0.jar 60 70 80 90 100

Comment: What did you do to troubleshoot this? Some intermediate logging of values would seem to be indicated.

Answer (score 2):

The graph is working as it should. Think about what's happening here:

1. you generate a lazy source of ints: `[1, 2, 3, ... 10]`
2. you multiple them by 10, so your stream is `[10, 20, 30 ... 100]`
3. you [**take**](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#take) the *first two elements* and complete the stream, **ignoring the rest**: `[10, 20]`
4. you filter the stream for those greater than 50, which excludes 10 and 20: `[]`

Therefore you print nothing.

If you remove the `take(2)` the full set of 10 elements will reach the sink and it'll print:

```
60
70
80
90
100
```

It's really just the same as running this in the Scala console (but lazier):

```
(1 to 10).map(_ * 10).take(2).filter(_ > 50).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.